# Can someone explain to me why $1/4(e^{-j2\pi/4}-e^{-j\pi6/4})=-1/2j\sin(k\pi/2)$?

Tags: calculus

Can someone explain to me why $$\frac{1}4(e^{-j2\pi/4}-e^{-j\pi6/4})= -\frac{1}2j\sin(k\pi/2)\;?$$

I know that is used Euler method, but still I can't get this...

Comment: First, but there is minus with with first e

Comment: Got it. tell me if my edit is correct (give me one edit).

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: I do not understand. There is no $k$ on the left side of the equation and the equation is clearly false when, for example, $k=0$. In the accepted answer, the left side of the equation is $\frac{1}{4}(e^{-ik\pi/2}-e^{ik\pi/2})$. Is that the correct expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that Euler's Formula is:
$$e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$
It follows that:
$$e^{-ix} = \cos(-x) + i\sin(-x)$$
Now, we have that $\cos$ is even, and $\sin$ is odd, so this simplifies to:
$$e^{-ix} = \cos(x) -i\sin(x)$$
Now, subtract the second from the first to get that:
$$e^{ix}-e^{-ix} = (\cos(x)-\cos(x)) +i\sin(x)- (-i\sin(x)) = 2i\sin(x)$$
This leads to:
$$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
So, we have that:
$$-\frac{1}{2} i \sin(k\pi/2) = -\frac{i}{2}(\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ik\pi/2}-e^{-ik\pi/2})) = -\frac{1}{4}(e^{ik\pi /2}-e^{-ik\pi/2}) = \frac{1}{4}(e^{-ik\pi/2}-e^{ik\pi/2})$$
Here, I use imaginary constant $i$ instead of $j$.

Comment: I see my mistake now -.-. Thank you.